# Перенос данных из базы данных на другом сервере

Tags: mysql

Можно ли как-либо перенести данные из базы данных на другом сервере скриптом?
Т.е., например, можно ли сделать это как-нибудь так, между двумя другими запросами?

```
insert  into `first_table`(`id`,`name`,`description`) values (643,'John','Описание');

/* запрос для переноса данных из базы данных другого сервера */

insert  into `third_table`(`id`,`name`,`description`) values (645,'Andrew','Описание');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать openquery или execute at.

Идея в том, что бы в цикле, перебирать таблицу которую нужно скопировать, с помощью xml path составлять строку данных для инсерта в другую таблицу, а потом запускать эту строку на нужном сервере.

Если табличка не большая, то можно обойтись без цикла.

По опыту скажу, что оптимальное количество строк за 1 инсерт я бы выбирал около 400. Ниже небольшой пример.

```
/*Формируем таблицу*/
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') is not null drop table #data
create table #data (id int, value int, value2 int)
insert into #data
select 1,1,500
union all
select 1,1,5500
union all
select 1,2,300
union all
select 1,2,3300


declare curs cursor for select id, value, value2 from #data --Курсор для таблички
declare @num as int = 3 -- Количество строк, которые будем инсертить за интерацию
declare @tmp as int = 0 -- Счетчик количества строк, которые будем инсертить за интерацию
declare @current_row as int = (select count(*) from #data) -- Счет всего строк в таблице.

declare @mainstr as varchar(max) = 'EXECUTE (''INSERT INTO dbo.base_to_insert (id, value, value2) VALUES ' -- Основная строка инсерта
declare @insert as varchar(max) = '' -- Строка с данными, которые будем инсертить

-- Переменные на каждую колонку в таблице
declare @id as int 
declare @value as int
declare @value2 as int

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @id, @value, @value2;

-- Цикл по строкам с таблице
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Формируем данные по каждой строке
    SET @insert = @insert + '(' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(@value AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(@value2 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
    SET @tmp = @tmp + 1
    SET @current_row = @current_row - 1
    -- Если табличка кончилось или мы засунули такое количество строк, котороу установили максимальным за одну интерацию, то инсертим на другой сервер
    IF @tmp = @num or @current_row = 0 BEGIN
        SET @tmp = 0
        -- Добавляем собранные данные к основной строке
        SET @mainstr = @mainstr + @insert + '''' + ' AT [linked_server])'
        SET @insert = ''
        -- Выполняем получившуюся строку
        PRINT @mainstr
        --EXECUTE sp_executesql @mainstr
        SET @mainstr = 'EXECUTE (''INSERT INTO dbo.base_to_insert (id, value, value2) VALUES '
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SET @insert = @insert + ','
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs
    INTO @id, @value, @value2;
END

CLOSE curs;
DEALLOCATE curs;
```

Comment: Человек же вроде спрашивал про MySQL. Какая автору вопроса польза от скрипта на T-SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. База работает только со своими данными, в MYSQL функций подключения к другим серверам нет. Перенос данных должен осуществляться через выгрузку в файл, после чего выполняется восстановление таблицы из этого файла, называемого дампом.

Возможен перенос из одной таблицы БД в другую, если они расположены на одном сервере:

```
INSERT INTO database2.mytable SELECT * FROM database1.mytable;
```

В другом случае, требуется пользоваться mysqldump и выполнять примерно следующие команды:

```
mysqldump -u имя_пользователя -p -h имя_сервера_БД имя_базы > dump.sql
```

Данные будут сохранены в файле dump.sql. Далее (в случае необходимости) восстанавливаем данные из резервной копии (дампа) так:

```
mysql -u имя_пользователя -p -h имя_сервера_БД имя_базы < dump.sql
```

**UPDATE:**

Спасибо пользователю **@nobody**, за подсказку, что есть такое понятие, как федеративные таблицы и с помощью них можно реализовать вашу операцию. Это будет медленее, чем загрузка данных через файл, но будет в рамках одного запроса.

Comment: "в MYSQL функций подключения к другим серверам нет" - а вот и нет, есть репликация :) Хотя в данном случае наверно всё равно не поможет